# Why does google crawl my page only once even I set changefreq:daily?

Tags: seo, google, sitemap

I have built a new site, submitted my homepage URL to Google, and my sitemap(I have about 6,300 pages.).

Now when I type `site:mydomain.com`, there have 1,992 pages have crawled. But they were all crawled at Jul 20(The day I sumbitted sitemap).

In my sitemap, I set different changefreq and priority for my different page URLs. But I have 3 pages set `changefreq:hourly` and at least 120 pages set `changefreq:daily`, 3,000 pages set  `changefreq:weekly` and the rest are `changefreq:monthly`. But why does Google not crawl my pages as I set `changefreq:hourly`, `changefreq:daily`?

My site is about news(from Bing api). Community, forum, photo, etc. now are in testing. In `www.google.com/analytics` every day I get about 15 visitors (most of them are our stuff) And in `www.google.com/webmasters`, my site now has `58 queries`, `2,500 impressions`.

How can I improve Google's crawl frequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot control crawl frequency except to reduce it in Google Webmaster Tools if you feel you are being crawled too much. Otherwise you have no direct control of increasing crawl rate. `changefreq` is a "guide" to the search engines for how often a page's content changes. But that doesn't affect how often they will crawl it.

Basic rules for anything Google: want Google to rank you better, index more pages, crawl you more frequently? get more high quality links to your pages.

Comment: yes, I want Google to rank me better, crawl you more frequently, get more high quality links to my pages. Do you have some good experience to show me? Thanks.

Comment: ,BTW, is `<lastmod>` important in a sitemap?

Comment: @cj333 lastmod will probably slow down crawling of that page, ie if a page has a date long ago it will be crawled less, but if it has a more recent date it will not necessarily speed up crawling. But it's worth adding.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat, ok, i will try to add `lastmod` and test again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you updating and adding pages on a daily basis? Because companies like Twitter and Technorati get updated instantly on the basis they update everyday and are considered a valuable source for info. Try enhancing the content along with the frequency of updates/crawls.

Comment: because my site is new, so in current, less pages be added every day. but at least 120 pages are updated daily.